# A student is picked up at random from a large class of students. If it is a boy is he he more likely to have more sisters than brothers?

Tags: probability

I supposed that the question asks me to prove $P(X\,has\,more\,sisters|X\,is\,a\,boy )>\frac12$ given probability of being a boy is $\frac12$ and it is equally likely for a parent to have a girl or boy child.
I tried to do this by Bayes' theorem but couldn't succeed. Any help?.

Comment: The first thing they are asking you isn't for a proof, it is whether the statement is true at all.

Comment: Yes but I want to know the reasoning behind the truthness.

Comment: Yes. He accounts for one of the boys in any expected 50/50 distribution of sibling genders.

Comment: @DavidDiaz this seems intuition. Is this a valid mathematical argument?

Comment: The question isn't well-defined. There are at least two problems. (a) The question appears to be making an assumption that there are exactly two possible genders; [this is not the case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex). (b) Even assuming two genders, the question provides no information about the distribution of males and females. The [human sex ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_sex_ratio) is known not to be equal to $\frac12$ at birth, and the mortality up to school age is a further unknown factor.

Comment: @DavidDiaz: No. It's not a matter of "accounting for". The question is implicitly (incorrectly) assuming a $50$/$50$ distribution of the genders independently per person, but not balanced families (that would be more obviously incorrect). If we knew we were dealing with a family consisting of half males and half females, then indeed the boy would "account for" one of these and observing him would raise the probability of the others being female. But that's not the case here. The others have independent uniform distributions that aren't influenced by one of their siblings being male.

Comment: @DavidDiaz: This is perhaps most easily seen by noting that the concept of siblings is in fact irrelevant here. Since gender is not genetically determined, the boy's siblings play no special role -- we might as well ask whether his seat neighbours have a higher probability of being female -- clearly they don't.

Comment: @joriki in the absence of guidance, it is reasonable to assume an expected binomial distribution of gender, independent of family size. Now the error that you and Christian below are making is ignoring the only data given: you know the gender of one of the siblings! This is a conditional probability problem: you expect a random family to have 50% boys and 50% girls. What is the expected gender ratio of a random family that has a boy, **after subtracting one boy**.

Comment: @DavidDiaz: The classroom has desks that seat two people. We expect a $50$/$50$ balance for each desk. We pick a student at random from the classroom and it turns out to be a boy. Is the student sharing a desk with him more likely to be a girl? If so, how much more likely and why? If not, how is that different from a family with two children?

Comment: @joriki consider four families called: BB, BG, GB, GG. We pick a random Boy. There is a 2/3 chance their sibling (or seat mate) is a girl.

Comment: @DavidDiaz: No. There are four boys, two of them have brothers, two have sisters.

Comment: @DavidDiaz: There's a $2/3$ chance if you uniformly randomly pick a family with a boy, then pick a boy from that family. That's a different experiment, one to which your "accounting for" paradigm applies, and it's not surprising that in that case there's an increased probability for a female sibling.

Comment: @joriki : Agreed. Mind blown. Thanks for your patience. I retract all my comments but leave them here to my eternal shame. May God have mercy on my soul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X has $n\geq0$ siblings. Their sexes are $B\bigl(n,{1\over2}\bigr)$ binomially distributed. It follows that X is not likely to have more sisters than brothers.

Comment: Can you explain how it follows that X is not likely to have more sisters than brothers. Intuition tells that he should have more sisters than brothers since he is a boy and it is expected that there would be equal number of girls and boys siblings in a family.

Comment: But he's not from a random family. The more boys a family has, the more likely one is chosen as X. It all balances out.   Intuitively, why should his number of sisters make a difference as to whether a boy is in the class.

Comment: @AshishRanjan: It is expected that there would be an equal number of rolls of each side when you roll a die. Nevertheless, rolling a $1$ doesn't make it less likely to roll a $1$ on subsequent rolls. The siblings are just like that. Their genders are independent, they each have their own independent $50$/$50$ distribution, so learning about one of them doesn't tell you anything about the others, just like with the dice.